# VB.NET - Troubleshooting IIS7 Active Directory Group Members Issue w/ Error Log Text File 

Tags: vb.net, iis-7, active-directory, active-directory-group

Background: I have an application that loads marketing companies into a drop down list if the currently logged in user is a member of that marketing group in active directory. The Group ACOMP_USER_BIG is compared to MarketingCompanyShortName Big in the database records via a web service.

Problem: I have 3 Newly added AD Groups that won't load in production but load fine in the drop down on my local dev server. The deployment guy already tried doing an IISReset and that didnt fix the issue. All the AD groups have read access only and no write access. We need to find out more information on why the marketing company AD groups are not loading.

How do I get the groups to load correctly or prove that the problem is not a programming issue and a deployment or AD issue?

H*ere's the VB.NET Code behind that populates the marketing company drop down list.

```
Private Sub GetMarketingCompanies()
    Try
        Dim marketingCompanyNamesArray As Array
        marketingCompanyNamesArray = proxy.GetMarketingCompanyNames("test", "test")

        ' code to populate marketing company drop down list based on the current logged in users active directory group that 
        ' corresponds to which marketing company they are in 

        Dim identityReferenceCollection As IdentityReferenceCollection
        Dim identityReference As IdentityReference
        identityReferenceCollection = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
        Dim strGroupName As String
        Dim mcisloaded As Boolean

        ' Translate the current user's active directory groups 
        For Each identityReference In identityReferenceCollection
            Dim mktGroup As IdentityReference = identityReference.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
            ' MsgBox(mktGroup.Value)
            ' Debug.WriteLine(mktGroup.Value) 
            strGroupName = mktGroup.Value.ToString

            ' Locally User group is ALG\ACOMP_USER_ADMIN , deployed ALGWEB\ACOMP_USER_ADMIN
            ' If the user is in the admin group, load all marketing companies   
            If mktGroup.Value = "ALG\ACOMP_USER_ADMIN" Then
                mcisloaded = True
                For Each item In marketingCompanyNamesArray
                    marketingCo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", item.MarketingCompanyShort, item.MarketingCompanyName))
                Next

            Else
                'If not admin user (mcisloaded = False) load each group individually if it appears in AD 
                ' For Each UserGroup In WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups that begins with ALG\ACOMP_USER, load marketing companies 

                Dim MarketingCompanyShortName As String = ""
                Dim mktGroupName As String = mktGroup.Value
                If mktGroupName.StartsWith("ALG\ACOMP_USER") Then
                    Dim marketingGroupNameParts() As String = Split(mktGroupName, "_")
                    'Load MarketingCompanyShortName from the end of marketingGroupNameParts - example: ACOMP_USER_BIG
                    MarketingCompanyShortName = marketingGroupNameParts(2)

                    'If MarketingCompanyShortName exists, load it into the dropdownlist 
                    Dim Company = marketingCompanyNamesArray.Cast(Of MarketingCompany).Where(Function(ac) ac.MarketingCompanyShort = MarketingCompanyShortName).FirstOrDefault
                    If Company IsNot Nothing Then
                        marketingCo.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", Company.MarketingCompanyShort, Company.MarketingCompanyName))
                    End If

                End If
            End If

        Next

        'END LOOP TO CHECK USER GROUPS 

    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteToEventLog(ex.Message, "GetMarketingCompanies-Method", EventLogEntryType.Error, "aComp-utility")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up Writing a webpage that that users having issues with their active directory settings can bring up that lists all active directory groups that a current user is in.

Here is the code to see:

- Current Logged in User's AD Credentials for Groups beginning with ALG\ACOMP_USER OR ALGWEB\ACOMP_USER
- Current Logged in User's AD Credentials for ALL Groups

see credentials.aspx.vb code-behind here:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports ACOMP_Invitation_Web_App.aComp_ServiceReference
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls


Public Class verifycredentials
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim identityReferenceCollection As IdentityReferenceCollection
    Dim identityReference As IdentityReference
    identityReferenceCollection = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Groups
    Dim strGroupName As String

    For Each identityReference In identityReferenceCollection
        Dim mktGroup As IdentityReference = identityReference.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
        ' MsgBox(mktGroup.Value)
        ' Debug.WriteLine(mktGroup.Value)
        strGroupName = mktGroup.Value.ToString

        Dim MarketingCompanyShortName As String = ""
        Dim mktGroupName As String = mktGroup.Value

        If mktGroupName.StartsWith("ALG\ACOMP_USER") Then
            Credentials.Text = Credentials.Text + mktGroup.Value + "<br>"
        End If
        If mktGroupName.StartsWith("ALGWEB\ACOMP_USER") Then
            Credentials.Text = Credentials.Text + mktGroup.Value + "<br>"
        End If
        If mktGroupName.StartsWith("ALG\ACOMP_user") Then
            Credentials.Text = Credentials.Text + mktGroup.Value + "<br>"
        End If
    Next
    For Each identityReference In identityReferenceCollection
        Dim mktGroup As IdentityReference = identityReference.Translate(GetType(NTAccount))
        ' MsgBox(mktGroup.Value)
        ' Debug.WriteLine(mktGroup.Value)
        strGroupName = mktGroup.Value.ToString

        Dim MarketingCompanyShortName As String = ""
        Dim mktGroupName As String = mktGroup.Value

        AllCredentials.Text = AllCredentials.Text + mktGroup.Value + "<br>"

    Next

End Sub
```

see credentials.aspx code here:

```
    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="credentials.aspx.vb" Inherits="ACOMP_Invitation_Web_App.verifycredentials" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

        <br />

    Current Logged in User&#39;s AD Credentials for Groups beginning with 
    ALG\ACOMP_USER OR ALGWEB\ACOMP_USER:<br /><br />

    <asp:Label ID="Credentials" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    Current Logged in User&#39;s AD Credentials for ALL Groups:<br /><br />

    <asp:Label ID="AllCredentials" runat="server"></asp:Label> 
    <br />
    <br />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Having users load this web application I was able to see what the user was seeing on their end and determined that users accessing the site remotely don't load their active directory group in IE under ALG\ACOMP_USER_COMPANY but only ALGWEB\ACOMP_USER_COMPANY and that's why some users were having problems.